# VBA - Compile error: wrong number of arguments

Tags: excel, vba

Not my code, but a co-worker asked for help with his macro. He was getting "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment." on the `Round()` function.

Here is his offending code:

```
Sub test()   
    starttime = Timer()

    'Processing here
    
    endtime = Timer()
    minutes = CInt((endtime - starttime) / 60)
    
    If minutes > CInt((endtime - starttime) / 60) Then
        seconds = Round((endtime - starttime) - ((minutes - 1) * 60), 2)  'Error is on this line
        minutes = minutes - 1
    Else
        seconds = Round(((endtime - starttime)) - (minutes * 60), 2)  'Error is on this line too
    End If
    
    MsgBox "Total Run Time: " & minutes & " minutes " & seconds & " seconds"
End Sub
```

It works for me and all his co-workers. I had him switch to `Application.WorksheetFunction.Round()` and that works fine. He had the same modules selected in **Tools > References**. The variables aren't defined in the code, so it should be using **Variant** and then set to **Integer** or **Single** at run time. I think I tried along the way to have him define the variables and we had the same error.

Any idea why `Round()` is causing an error just for him?

Comment: Does he have another subroutine or function called `Round` in his code? Also he can put `VBA.` before `Round`, but note that `VBA.Round` and `WorksheetFunction.Round` don't behave the same (the former uses bankers rounding).

Comment: We scanned through the code quickly, but that would be worth another look. It makes perfect sense, and I just tested it and it does cause this error! I wondered if VBA.Round would force it to come from the VBA library but I never tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BigBen got it right. I had my coworker search his VBA Project for "Round" and he found he had a sub named Round. I told him that was a bad name and he should pick something else!